# How to Obfuscate SQL Sprocs?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, obfuscation

Is there a way to hide/protect/obfuscate MS SQL Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 10):

I can vaguely understand obfuscating code if it's extremely advanced in what it does, but I think obfuscating your SQL may not be worth the hassle.

Anyway, a lot of the SQL I've seen around here comes obfuscated as standard.

Comment: Haha, only because you don’t get the genuis of all these fine SQL statements it doesn’t mean that they are obfuscated. You genius-fu is simply too weak. ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you must hide it, how about the "WITH ENCRYPTION" clause?

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/01/sql-server-explanation-of-with-encryption-clause-for-stored-procedure-and-user-defined-functions/

Answer (score 6):

See the ENCRYPTION option for the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: This method is not really helpful it can be easily decrypted see https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/download.html

Answer (score 4):

No. At least, not in a way that is irreversible. SQL Server 2000's "WITH ENCRYPTION" can be reversed to get the original plaintext. The pseudo-code and a T-SQL script that illustrates this is here:
http://education.sqlfarms.com/education/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=783

Note: I haven't tried it with SQL 2005 or above, but my guess is it is just as vulnerable.. As the MSDN docs state:

> ENCRYPTION
>       Indicates that SQL Server will convert the original text of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement to an **obfuscated** format.

Emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to place just the sensitive portions of the stored procedure in a CLR stored procedure, and obfuscate that assembly using a professional obfuscation product.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Easily reversible if you know but intimidating to to most people poking around code. 
hex encode you sproc logic and then execute with EXEC(@hexEncodedString).
see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200545/attempted-sql-injection-attack-what-are-they-trying-to-do).

Answer (score 2):

Old post, I know.  But I got here from searching 'Why should I obfuscate SQL?'  I just installed a free product called ApexSQL Refactor (no affiliation) which offers an obfuscation component.

It offers several different options for making your code hard to read.  I wasn't sure why I'd want such a feature given, as others noted the ability to encrypt your stored procedures.  Anyway, this is an example of the output it can return from it's obfuscation function.

```
CrEAtE Procedure spInsertOrUpdateProduct @ProductNumber nVarChar(25),
@ListPrice Money aS IF exIsTS(selECt * FROm Production.Product WHere
ProductNumber=@ProductNumber AnD ListPrice>1000) uPdatE Production.
Product sET ListPrice=(ListPrice-100) where ProductNumber=
@ProductNumber elsE INSerT intO Production.Product(ProductNumber,
ListPrice) SelECT @ProductNumber,@ListPrice GO SElEct * fRoM
Production.Product gO iNsERT iNTo Production.UnitMeasure(
UnitMeasureCode,Name,ModifiedDate) vAlUeS(N'FT2',N'Square Feet',
'20080923'); Go
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ENCRYPTION clause when creating the stored procedure.

This would rely on not leaving the source SQL on the customer machine though.

See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can always write ordinary code in C# (or VB) and store it outside the database in a DLL.

Then you don't have to worry about obfuscating your SQL.

Comment: Yes, but those dll's can be just as easily decompiled, so you'd need to obfuscate, so you're back at square 1.

Comment: Everything executable can be decompiled and reverse engineered.  So you can't get off square 1.  Why bother?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really worried about someone getting into the DB and seeing the source for the procedure, then as S. Lott said, you can port the procedure to C#.  I would recommend LINQ.

However, the database itself should probably be protected from people accessing the code for procedures that shouldn't be.  You can restrict a user or group's rights to only have EXECUTE access to a proc if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool to obfuscate sql https://harrymoreno.com/sql-obfuscator/

it replaces table and column names with letters